# Symfony Rest Api, form without name for Android

Tags: php, android, forms, symfony

I have a RestApi with Symfony2 and a form for create a new account.

I'm using this API for an Android application and i have a problem.

If i name my form, for example `my_project_form_account`, symfony wait a POST variable named `my_project_form_account[my_field]`.

But on Android, i can't use `[]`, so, my solution, i have remove the name of my form, and now i can just send `my_field`.

But now, i have a form without name, and i don't like it..

Do you have a solution for me ? If i name my form, is there a way to not send `my_project_form_account[my_field]` ?

In Symfony, i retrieve POSt with :

```
        $jsonData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $form->bind($jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

To just upload the form data (when using the Symfony generated form data) rather than the whole form you can use..

```
$form->submit($request->get($form->getName()));
```

If your original form data (generated by Symfony with the form name "form_name") would have been in this format..

```
form_name:
    field1: value1
    field2: value2
```

.. you would actually be just submitting..

```
field1: value1
field2: value2
```

.. and it works just the same.

This means that when you are only supplying the "form_data" array you could supply all of the POST data to the form to submit like so..

```
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```